# R Shiny dependent selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have found several largely similar topics but couldn't figure out how to solve my problem so I kindly ask for help:

I have two `selectInput`, where the second one should depend on the first. The labels and values (which I need to plot a graph) come from a data.frame. How can I restrict the options and thus values in the second selectInput, depending on the choice made in the first one?

I tried using `observeEvent` but there but be something missing. Here's a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

method1 <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
value1 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
method2 <- c("X","Y","X","Y","X","Y")
value2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(method1, value1, method2, value2)

val1 <- setNames(df$value1, df$method1)

ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("m1", 
                      "Method1",
                      choices = val1,
                      selected = "A"),
          selectInput("m2", 
                      "Method2",
                      choices = NULL)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$m1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'m2',
                      choices=setNames(df$value2[df$method1==input$m1], df$method2[df$method1==input$m1]))})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**

For the minimal example dataset @brittenbs suggestions to replace `df$method1 == input$m1` with `df$value1 == as.numeric(input$m1)` solves the problem.

For my bigger real life dataset I used a workaround by building a reactive dataset

```
dft <- reactive({df %>% filter(value1 == as.numeric(input$m1))})
```

and call that in `observeEvent`

```
observeEvent(input$m1,{ updateSelectInput(session,'m2', choices=setNames(dft()$value2, dft()$method2))})
```

Comment: What happens when you choose an option from `m1`? Does it just do nothing? Do you get an error? Does it give the wrong results?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. m2 is completely blank with no options to choose from.

Comment: This is because you're expecting `input$m1` to return 'A' or 'B' or 'C', right? But in reality, those are just the labels presented to the user. The underlying values that are returned are the 1, 2, and 3. But you also have to keep in mind that the input returns those values as characters. So `input$m1` is actually returning `"1"` when it's set to `"A"`, and `df$method1` will never equal "1".

Comment: A very good point, I completely missed that! Let's see if that helps me figure out a solution

Comment: You should be able to just replace `df$method1 == input$m1` with `df$value1 == as.numeric(input$m1)`.

Comment: I provided a solution but you mentioned that your situation is different in the real world and not reflected in the example - could you please give me an updated example so that I can update the solution accordingly?